# Two similar first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve$$tx'^2-2xx'-t=0$$
>   and
>   $$t^2-2txx'-x^2=0$$

These would be easy Riccati's equations if their middle terms werent multiplied by 2. In this case I have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

**I would say that the second equation**

$t^2-2txx'-x^2=0$

goes substitutions $x^2=z \Rightarrow 2xx'=z'\,$ the linear equation $z'-z/t=t$

$\Rightarrow z = c/t+t^2/3 \Rightarrow |x| = \sqrt{c/t+t^2/3}$

**Edit - addet the first equation:**

$\displaystyle tx'^2-2xx'-t=0 \Rightarrow x'_{1,2}=\frac{x}{t}\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2+1}$

Substitution $x = zt \Rightarrow x'=z't+z \Rightarrow$

1. $z't + z = z + \sqrt{z^2+1} \Rightarrow \int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}\,dz=\int \frac{dt}{t}\Rightarrow z = \sinh(c+\ln|t|)\Rightarrow $

   $x = t\sinh(c+\ln|t|)$
2. $z't + z = z - \sqrt{z^2+1}  \Rightarrow $solve like ad 1.